# jQuery UI Sortable items not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a table with sortable rows with jQuery UI. I already have this working, but I intend on only sort some rows (not all of them) based on a checkbox.

I uploaded the code to http://jsfiddle.net/detesto/7Tcgc/3/

When the checkbox changes, I add or remove the class that should trigger the sortable row. The problem is that when it is removed, it doesn't work as expected.

I also tried doing a refresh on the sortble `$("#selector").sortable("refresh");` but this doesn't work for me either.

I have it working by cancelling the event if the user drags a non-valid row, but I would like to prevent this altogether.

Can this be prevented?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutOnce);
    timeoutOnce = setTimeout(reorderRows, 300);
    $("#fileTable tbody").sortable({
        helper: fixHelper,
        items: "> tr.doSort",
        cancel: ".noSort"   //---- add
    }).disableSelection();
}).on("click", ".enableDisable", function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("noSort").addClass("doSort");
        //$("#fileTable tbody").sortable("refresh"); // --- remove
    } else {
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("noSort").removeClass("doSort");
        //$("#fileTable tbody").sortable("refresh"); // --- remove
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I saw the cancel method, but I oversaw the option.